# Angular: How to filter nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this website http://ocr-photos.dk/

Currently the data is store in one array like this (and this works fine):

```js
$scope.data = [
      {
        category: 'FundRacers',
        title: 'FundRacers Events',
        link: 'https://www.facebook.com/FundRacersDK/',
        order: '1000',
        children: [
         { category: "FundRacers", event: "FundRacers Påsketrænning", year: "2017-04-14", fotograf: "Nikolaj Borup", link: "https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1930098447223523.1073741963.1543490649217640&type=1&l=dce31258df", link2: "" }
        , { category: "FundRacers", event: "FundRacers GetFitGym Event", year: "2016-12-10", fotograf: "Lena Toft Pedersen og Filip Rasmussen", link: "https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1867935790106456.1073741957.1543490649217640&type=1&l=db17b724a0", link2: "" }
        ]
      },
      {
        category: 'Evolution Race',
        title: 'Evolution Race',
        link: 'https://www.facebook.com/evolutionrace/',
        order: '1100',
        children: [
         { category: "Evolution Race", event: "Sky", year: "2017-06-04", fotograf: "Jens Petersen", link: "https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10155273811362660.1073741862.290365527659&type=1&l=e4df786a18", link2: "" }
        , { category: "Evolution Race", event: "Sky", year: "2017-06-04", fotograf: "Tommy Jensen", link: "https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1953270791572955.1073741972.1543490649217640&type=1&l=04c3a9e905", link2: "" }
        ]
      },
      }
      ];
```

I would like to change the data to be contained in two arrays, one with categories and one with the links. But when doing that I am having trouble getting the filter for the nested ng-repeat to work properly.

The first ng-repeat looks like this

```html
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:'order'">
```

The second looks like this:

```html
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="child in item.children | filter:searchText  | orderBy:'-year'"><a href="{{child.link }}" target="_blank">{{ child.year }} - {{ child.event }} - Fotograf {{ child.fotograf }}</a></li>
```

If I change the data like this

```html
      $scope.category = [
      { category: 'FundRacers', title: 'FundRacers Events',link: 'https://www.facebook.com/FundRacersDK/', order: '1000'} }
      ];


      $scope.links = [
      { category: "FundRacers", event: "FundRacers Påsketrænning", year: "2017-04-14", fotograf: "Nikolaj Borup", link: "https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1930098447223523.1073741963.1543490649217640&type=1&l=dce31258df", link2: "" }
      ];
```

How should I change my two ng-repeat to give the same result?

I have tried several different versions og the nested ng-repeat

```html
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="cat in category | orderBy:'order'">

<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="link in links | filter:cat.category"></li>

<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="link in links | filter:{{cat.category}}"></li>

<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="link in links | filter:'cat.category'"></li>
```

Nothing worked so far. Either I get the entire list in each category or I get nothing.

Comment: Your first solution is good why would you change this ?

Comment: I want to change it because I want to be able to list all links sorted on link name and other views which I cannot see possible with the current data structure.

Comment: You can do this in your second ng repeat: {{$index + 1}} for able your li with index from your element in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. Stupid typo error.

This works

```html
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="link in links | filter:cat.category"></li>
```